# Random number generator in Matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging, random

I am generating random sequences of numbers using the same seed:

```
sprev = rng(2,'v5uniform');
for i=1:N
    %do some operations      
    rndIDX = randperm(sampleSize) ; 
    newdata= data(rndIDX(1:newSampleSize), :) ;
    if x>y
       remove=x1; %line 7
    end
    for l=1:M
        %do something else
        if l>xy & ~empty(remove)
           %do something related to remove
        elseif l>xy
           %do nothing
        else
           %do something not related to remove
        end
        %more code here
    end
 end
```

However, when I comment out line 7, rndIDX returns a different sequence of numbers which for me is unexpected. There might be a bug somewhere in the code but I am not sure what is the relationship between the sequence produced by `randperm` and the code that follows. Also, if i keep the code as presented I always get the same newdata which is the expected behaviour. I just want to comment out line 7 and still get the same newdata.I can confirm that `sampleSize` is always the same as well as `newSampleSize` for both cases.

Comment: Are you calling any form of other random number generator in any of those blocks that you've chosen not to show? Your code is not runnable and does not replicate the error you claim. Reduce your code down to the minimal runnable case that reproduces your issue. Also, you should probably be using a short-circuit AND, i.e., `&&` instead of `&`.

Comment: In addition to horchler's comment, in order for anyone to answer your question we'd want to know what is `rndINDX`, `sampleSize`, `data`, `remove`, `x`, `y`, `x1`, `l`, `M`, `xy` (you get the idea). For your code to do something different when you comment out a line is entirely to be expected! If your code ran the same after commenting out a line then I'd suggest the line was a waste of time in the first place.

Comment: @horchler i am not calling any other number generator + i do not have `&&`.